# Nusach Sefard vs. Nusach Ha-Arizal

Tags: chabad, chasidut-hasidism, nusach-sefard, nusach-ari

So I was wondering what differences there are between Nusach Sefard, the traditional Chassidic nusach and Nusach Ha-Arizal, the Chabadnik nusach arranged by the Alter Rebbe (Rabbi Schneur Zalman of Liadi). Does anyone know the difference?

Comment: Is there really only one Nusach Sefard??

Comment: @DoubleAA You're correct; there really isn't just ONE, but I'm just saying, for example, I dunno, like Artscroll's?

Comment: Well if it matters to you you should specify. And frankly if it doesn't matter to you you should specify.

Comment: There is also more than one Nusach Ha-Ari.

Comment: The nusach of the Ari z"l is only referring to the specific format for prayer taught by Rabbi Yitzchok Luria. There are different nusachot which try to incorporate what the Ari taught but add or alter. The Alter Rebbe's nusach is 'according to' the nusach of the Ari z"l. It is not the Ari's nusach precisely.

Comment: I was under the impression Nusach Ha-Arizal was the precursor to Nusach Sefard. Nusach Sefard being an umbrella term for the various Chassidic Nusach.

Comment: @ The BST introduced included in Ashkenazic Tefila some changes and additions following Sifre Kabbala of the Arizalic litterature. The Chabbad sidur is 1 of the examples of such combinations. Tefila Yeshara too.

Comment: The Ari was a real sefardi and he made changes in that nusach. Today there is a newly printed siddur Ari with his correct nusach, meaning the original sefardi nusach with his changes.  The chasidic nusach sefard today especially in shmone esrai has no "mkor" but was made by the printers.  Belz for instance uses the ashkenaz shmone esrai with very slight variations. There is only one Ashkenaz nusach said by people from all over Europe and Russia whereas with sefard every printer made a different one. The chasam sofer has said there is nothing wrong with nusach ashkenaz only we didnt have an Ari

Comment: Background to the creation of the Siddur of the Baal HaTanya: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2089176/jewish/The-Chassidic-Prayerbook.htm

Comment: @newcomer - The Ari was a real Ashkenazi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Luria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nusach Sefard, Nusach Sepharad, or Nusach Sfard is the name for various forms of the Jewish siddurim, designed to reconcile Ashkenazi customs (Hebrew: מנהג "Custom", pl. minhagim) with the kabbalistic customs of Isaac Luria.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nusach_Sefard

Technically speaking, the Alter Rebbe's siddur is a form of nuschach sefard.

> Nusach Ari is a variant of Nusach Sefard, used by Chabad Hasidim.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nusach

Practically speaking, no one calls it Nusach sephard (even wikipedia separates it from Nusach sefard). My guess would be that's because of the separation between chabad and other Chassidim. Either way, Chabad definitely views it as separate nuschaos. I can't speak for the other Chassidim though, and I haven't asked them. But they're both founded from the same sources, and share many similarities.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that Nusach Sfard is the nusach that was created by those who wished to incorporate the customs of the Ari.

Many different versions of Nusach Sfard have existed and because of this there has been many attempts by various Chassidishe groups to reconcile the differences amongst versions into one standard version for their group.

The most prominent of these redacted versions is the Chabad version of Nusach Sfard which they call Nusach AriZaL. This was the Alter Rebbe's attempt to standardise Nusach Sfard for his Chassidim.

All of the versions of Nusach Sfard, including Nusach AriZaL, are quite similar. I myself use an Artscroll Nusach Sfard siddur and daaven by a Chabad shule and I get by with very little difficulty whatsoever.

Comment: One difference would be minor differences in Yishtabach, Morning Brachos, and the tefilla right before Shemoneh Esrei (ArtScroll Nusach Sefard shows Tzur Yisroel.)

Comment: There's many but they're quite minor.

Comment: Yes, that's for sure. I think ArtScroll is much better than Kehot, so I would do the same thing in a Chabad shul.