# Is Nusach al-pi Arizal davened by anyone besides Chabad?

Tags: prayer-book, chabad, chasidut-hasidism, nusach-sefard, nusach-ari

Are there any other Chasidic sects besides Chabad that daven Nusach al-pi Arizal (Siddur Tehillas Hashem or Torah Ohr)?

Comment: Note many Siddurim have claimed to be "the nusach of the Arizal". Chabad's is but one of them. So other groups can pray with such a nusach, but not have it be that of Chabad's. (related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70798/759 )

Comment: I've known several non-_Chabad_ people who use _Tehillat Hashem_… but you ask about sects.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Yes I know that. That is why I specifically said "Siddur Tehillas Hashem and Torah Ohr." As in, the siddur according to the Arizal as interpreted by the Baal HaTanya.

Comment: @msh210 - I have also known individuals, such as people who attend Chabad houses but are not Chabad. But I am talking sects here...

Comment: Nobody davens nusach Ari. Shaar Hakavanos brings down that Arizal did not want anyone to change from nusach ashkenaz to nusach sfard (like he prayed) so that they shouldn't lose out on their particular pathway of prayer. Apparently people thought the better idea would then be to make up a new nusach, nusach sfard to incorporate what they thought was the best of both nuschaos. So in reality all nusach sfard are an attempt at nusach ari, to some degree or another. All perhaps ignoring his imploring them to keep to nusach ashkenaz.

Comment: it is likely that other chassidim who use the same siddur if any have their own publications by now. Over time there have been breakways from chabad mostly due to disagreement over leadership apposed to any sort of philosophical difference. If these groups still exist they would probably still use the same text of the siddur. Although I can't be 100% certain but it would make sense if they did.

Comment: *Over time there have been breakways from chabad mostly due to disagreement over leadership apposed to any sort of philosophical difference.* Most breakaways died out over the years

Comment: @user6591 Curious, what are the differences between Nusach Chabad and "real" HaAri?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, Malachim?

Comment: @user6591, Treasures of Ashkenaz mentions this on their blog (of all sources to cite R"I Luria approvingly, this is near the bottom of my list of general suspects FWIW)

Comment: @SAH There is no real nusach Ari. He used the same nusach as all sefardim being that he was sefardi. Maybe what you and I would call nusach edat mizrach.

Comment: @Noach that is funny. iirc sheroshei minhag ashkenaz also quoted some unlikely sources in their anti kabbala installment. With funny lines like al tikabel hakabala.

Comment: @user6591, R' Yitzchak Luria **Ashkenazi** was Sephardi? He followed Sephardi minhagim because he was brought up by his mother's family, his father having died when he was young IIRC. Also, I'm unsurprised about a weird source in ShM"A, the Yosef Ometz brings the Sha'ar haKavvanot in his sefer, and he was certainly a choshuv Frankfurter Jekke.

Comment: @Noach you are correct. What I meant is that he acted in accordance with sfardi minhagim. Now that you mention it, that fact makes that entry in shaar hakavanos even more interesting. Shouldn't Arizal have changed back to nusach ashkenaz as that was his father's minhag, i.e. his shevet's minhag?

Comment: @6591, does a b"t change their minhag to their ancestors' if they were b"t under a rav of a different custom?

Comment: @Noach some poskim discuss changing back to one's original nusach if something happened along the way that diverted it. Reb Moshe Feinstein and most others say to change back from nusach sfard (not sfardi) to ashkenaz as that was the original for all ashkenazim. Rabbi Yaakov Kaminetzky was from the minority who said to change back from ashkenaz to sfard as that is the nusach hakolel ( that's the terminology used to justify it's existence) and yes, Reb Y. K. davened nusach sfard:) But my point was more because Arizal said ones tefilos might not actually reach Hashem if he is using the wrong

Comment: Cont. nussach. Seems strange that he himself was!

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt In Chabad itself, they hold that you can't (maybe with exception) "descend" from a Nusach Ari back to nusach Ashkenaz or whatever. This presumably includes the many baalei teshuvah whose ancestors davened nusach Ashkenaz

Comment: @SAH, in Chabad they hold that "Nusach Ari" is the "Sha'ar haKollel" (an 'inyan for which I have much disdain) however this goes against rov haposkim. R' Moshe Feinstein זצ"ל, the pre-eminent 20th century American posek held that switching from Nusach Sfard (including Chabad's variant) to Nusach Ashkenaz was not a yeridah, as it was a more modern adoption (his father was a chassid by birth and upbringing, although he "did teshuvah" and became Litvish for his shidduch)

Comment: @SAH, bekitzur, it's not a yeridah. Rather, it's switching from a patched together seder (much more evident in non-Chabad Sfard siddurim) to a more accepted seder.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Interesting; yes, I mean, that's essentially what you said earlier. I'm just reporting Chabad's (or perhaps the chasidic) view of the matter

Comment: There are many versions of nusach arizal. Other chasidim use nusach sephard of which there variations. Also the alter rebbe's siddur itself was put together by alter rebbe studying 60 different versions of the arizal's nusach

Answer (score 3):

I do believe that those followers of Rabbi Chaim Avraham Dov Ber Levine HaCohen ([the Malachim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malachim_(Hasidic_group))) also daven the Chabad nusach. This is anecdotal, as I went to yeshiva with someone whose family identified with this group and he used a Tehillat haShem siddur.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Shmuel

Comment: That sounds right, as the Malachim did split from Lubavitch.

Comment: The Malochim are also Chabad. They just never accepted the seventh Rebbe of Lubavitch - R' Menachem Mendel Schneerson. I specifically asked for sects other than Chabad.

Comment: @ezra they didn't accept *any* of the last four Rebbes. The last one they held of was the Tzemach Tzedek. Maybe the Rebbe Maharash, as they split off in the lifetime of the Rebbe Rashab (who passed away in 1920).

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, wasn't their problem some loshon horo about R' Sh"B's son reading secular Russian newspapers? Why that should be a problem is beyond me, but I recall hearing that somewhere.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt And that the Rebbe Rashab sided with his son over the Malach.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin - Yet that still makes them Chabad.